# How do I find the class definition for decimal.Decimal?

Tags: python, class, module, decimal

I'm trying to find the definition of `decimal.Decimal` but I don't know how.

I tried using inspect but it says `OSError: could not find class definition`. Can anyone tell me how I would do this? Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A normal CPython installation will have a C implementation in `_decimal` and a Python implementation in `_pydecimal`, which could be what is confusing `inspect`. The Python implementation is used as a [fallback](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.12.0/Lib/decimal.py#L2-L11) if the C implementation is unavailable.

- **Python implementation**: find it [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.12.0/Lib/_pydecimal.py#L523) in `Lib/_pydecimal.py`.
- **C implementation**: find it [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.12.0/Modules/_decimal/_decimal.c#L72-L77) in `Modules/_decimal/_decimal.c`.